# RXJS chain subscriptions anti-pattern with NGRX

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have the following code, which is working, but I've read that chaining subscriptions is an anti-pattern.  I need to make sure that the user has a loggedin state of true, before making a call to the API which requires the users authtoken.

What would be the proper way to handle this in RXJS?

```
const subscrAuth = this.store
  .pipe(select(isLoggedIn))
  .subscribe(isLoggedIn => {
    console.log(isLoggedIn);
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      const subscrLoaded = this.store
        .pipe(select(hasCarriersLoaded))
        .subscribe(hasCarrierLoaded => {
          if (!hasCarrierLoaded) {
            this.store.dispatch(new CarriersPageRequested());
          }
        });
    }
  });
this.unsubscribe.push(subscrAuth);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just an API call, you wouldn't need to unsubscribe, because it completes by itself. You can use `switchMap` to chain and `filter` to.. filter :). And you have a nice chain of rxjs operators, which self completes

```
this.store.pipe(
  select(isLoggedIn),
  take(1),
  filter((isLoggedIn) => isLoggedIn),
  switchMapTo(this.store),
  select(hasCarriersLoaded),
  take(1),
  filter((hasCarriersLoaded) => !hasCarriersLoaded),
).subscribe(() => this.store.dispatch(new CarriersPageRequested()));
```

It feels like though that you can combine the two selects:

```
combineLatest([
  this.store.pipe(select(isLoggedIn)),
  this.store.pipe(select(hasCarriersLoaded))
]).pipe(
  take(1),
  filter(([loggedIn, hasCarriers]) => loggedIn && !hasCarriers)
).subscribe(() => this.store.dispatch(new CarriersPageRequested()));
```

If you however need to wait before the user is logged in, while handling this request, you can do the following:

```
combineLatest([
  this.store.pipe(select(hasCarriersLoaded)),
  this.store.pipe(
    select(isLoggedIn),
    filter((loggedIn) => loggedIn)
  )
]).pipe(
  take(1),
  filter(([hasCarriers]) => !hasCarriers)
).subscribe(() => this.store.dispatch(new CarriersPageRequested()));
```

If you also need to wait to be logged in to call `hasCarriersLoaded`, you should switch the `filter` with the `take(1)` in the first example

Comment: You always need to unsubscribe as a best practice. Angular does do a complete on the response of http but it can still introduce a memory leak if the user navigates away from the page or does some other action before complete() is fired.

Comment: This is an excellent answer.  I had to update the switchmapto --> switchMapTo(this.store.pipe(select(hasCarriersLoaded)))

Comment: @tuckerjt07 the observable completes by itself. Only in the case where you wait for a `loggedIn` status you should use a `takeUntil(destroy)`. Nevertheless, to me it feels like the above code should be placed in a service, and not in a component. In a component you should preferably not use `subscribe` at all, and just rely on the `async` pipe in your template to handle the subscriptions. Clean code is happy code

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
const subscrAuth = this.store
.pipe(
  select(isLoggedIn),
  switchMap(isLoggedIn => {
    this.store.pipe(
      select(hasCarriersLoaded),
      tap(hasCarriersLoaded => {
        this.store.dispatch(new CarriersPageRequested());
      })
     )
  })
).subscribe();
this.unsubscribe.push(subscrAuth);
```

I'd also recommend either using the ngOnDestroy function to manage your subscriptions like so,

```
onDestroy$: Subject<null> = new Subject();

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.onDestroy$.next();
}

this.store
.pipe(
  takeUntil(this.onDestroy$),
  select(isLoggedIn),
  switchMap(isLoggedIn => {
    this.store.pipe(
      select(hasCarriersLoaded),
      tap(hasCarriersLoaded => {
        this.store.dispatch(new CarriersPageRequested());
      })
     )
  })
).subscribe();
```

or if you are only going to be making a single call you could also modify the pipe like so

```
this.store
.pipe(
  take(1),
  select(isLoggedIn),
  switchMap(isLoggedIn => {
    this.store.pipe(
      select(hasCarriersLoaded),
      tap(hasCarriersLoaded => {
        this.store.dispatch(new CarriersPageRequested());
      })
     )
  })
).subscribe();
```

Comment: thank you, the line "switchMap(isLoggedIn => {" had an issue for me.  Also thanks for the advice on the destroying subscriptions!

Comment: You should remove the `{` inside the switchMap or add `return` to the inner observable. Nothing returns right now.